# Detect if a user is already in a list in DOM and then move there sort position if they are in the list with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In my Project Management app built mostly with JavaScript,  I would like to show a thumbnail image of all users who have made any edits or comments on a Task record just like Github Issues do....

[image]

---

**Some features**

- The list of users will be loaded as JSON.
- JSON contributor list of users will include the users Name, ID, image URL, and DateTime of there last activity
- If the edit a task and they are not in the user list already then they will be added using AJAX to save to DB and then update the DOM adding there image and data to the front 1st position of the images list.
- If the user edits a Task record and they are already in the user list.  Then the DB will be updated with the new sort position and DateTime of the activity.  The DOM will then be updated to move there Image to the 1st position on the user list of images.

  ```
  if( USER_IS_IN_CONTRIBUTOR_LIST ){

      (1)
      // Update DOM to move there thumbnail image from its current sort position 
      // into the 1st position and update the DateTime value that will be in the  
      // HTML Title attribute with there Username (when you hover over the  
      // thumbnail images it will show there username and the DateTime of there  
      // activity using the Title attribute filed).

      (2)  
      // Make AJAX request to server to update/save the new data for the  
      // contributor list on this task record.

  }ELSE{
  // User is not in the existing Contributors list so we need to add them.

      (1)
      // Update Contributors list in the DOM, adding a new record for the new  
      // user to show there thumbvnail image in the 1st position spot on the list.

      (2)  
      // Make AJAX request to server to update/save the new data for the  
      // contributor list on this task record.

  }
  ```

---

**Questions**

**1)**
The contributor list of users will generally be less than 10 users.
I have 2 obvious choices that nstand out to me based on the fact that I need to at least store the User ID and DateTime of the action for each contributor in the list.

**A)** Store the list in my Task MySQL DB table in a contributors column in JSON format.

**B)** Create a new MySQL DB table for task contributors which would hold a record for every user on every task that they touch.  The nice part is all the sorting would be handled automatically by simply sorting on the DateTime field.

How would you store the list of contributor users for each task record?

---

**2)**
I mostly need help with the Javascript to do my mockup code posted above.

A)  I need help checking to see if the contributor already exist in my contributors list in the DOM.

B) If they exist in the DOM list from question 2-A,  I need help with the process of moving them to spot #1.  Removing them from there current sort position in the DOM list and adding them back to sort position number 1 in the front of the list.  Also it needs to update the HTML Title attribute with the new DateTime value.

C) If the contributor does not exist in the DOM list yet, then I think I can simply pre-pend them to the front of the list.

---

**3)**
Building the list of contributors from JSON.  The JSON will consist of these values for each user in the list:

- User ID
- User name
- User avatar image URL
- DateTIme from when the users contribution was made.

Desired solution will simply be like Github issues in this image...

[image]

<div id="contributors-list">
    <a class="contributors-toggle">
        <strong>3</strong> contributors
    </a>
  
    <a class="avatar-link tooltipped tooltipped-s" aria-label="dennyferra" href="#">
      <img alt="@dennyferra" class="avatar" height="20" src="https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/244942?v=3&amp;s=40&quot; width="20">
    </a>
    <a class="avatar-link tooltipped tooltipped-s" aria-label="MarQuisKnox" href="">
      <img alt="@MarQuisKnox" class="avatar" height="20" src="https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/789594?v=3&amp;s=40&quot; width="20">
    </a>
    <a class="avatar-link tooltipped tooltipped-s" aria-label="josephruscio" href="">
      <img alt="@josephruscio" class="avatar" height="20" src="https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/73915?v=3&amp;s=40&quot; width="20">
    </a>
</div>

---

Any help appreciated.

JSFiddle coming soon

Comment: For first question you should really specofy what DB technology you using.
For second - dom structure is requred for prescie answer. Genral plot should be like this: $(selector_for_user_dom_element).each(function(i){if(getUserNameFromDomElement(this) == newUser name) {$(parentSelector).prepend(this)}})

Comment: @Dmitry MySQL.  I will update it to say that.   Also simplifying my post

Comment: Why wouldn't you just save the contributor immediately and return the ordered list of contributors, updating the view wholesale? It seems like you are designing the list such that there is no single source of truth.

Comment: @Mathletics so you are saying instead of adding the 1 contributor to the list, instead rebuild the whole list each time right?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to remove all of the noise about background stuff, include a [mcve] that we can work with, and slim it down to asking one question (which is hopefully not opinion based). Otherwise this is closeable for multiple different reasons.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time... it's far too broad...

Comment: Tell me about your DB requirements:

Comment: do you need database speed? 
do you estimate more users or files?
how often do u think users will modify?

Comment: I am trying to delete, I realize I made a mistake and in the process solved most my issues

Answer (score 0):

1st question:

storing json in sql is using not normalized data in normalized-oriented db, so second solution will be preferred for record integrity. Ofcourse, if there ate many files, you will have a big JOIN each time, will slow down DB, but still loading a big JSON and parsing it in Web Server will slow the server, so is up on your estimations. And some tests.
**Usualy you use un-normalized DB (like cassandra) for 2D tables**

I will not suggest you to bother the server with sorting.

Each time someone modify, you send an AJAX notice to server, server test if user exist in the list and update timestamp or add user + set timestamp.

When you load users icons, you simply generate a unsorted JSON package on server and send it. Then JavaScript will sort it and organize pictures.

2nd question:

I would not lose time to move pictures inside DOM tree, but after sending AJAX notice of modify, will reload the users JSON from server and upload again pictures, more safe to keep page sync with server.

So u need just a single function that load, parse, and build DOM, not search, check and modify.

Comment: Now is done... those '1st question' mean 'my ANSWER to 1st question'

Comment: Oh I see now, your answer is just a big opinion statement with no facts to back it up. Well I guess that isn't really your fault, the off-topic too-broad opinion-based question is asking for that.

Comment: Yes, i think the guy know how to script down, so it will fix it up its own, just asking about the best way to do it, so i gave him my opinion.

Comment: Well opinion based questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow for future reference. If the question is truly asking for an opinion, it is off-topic and therefor should not be answered. Stack Overflow is about Factual Answers to Questions, not opinions.

Comment: Would you mind deleting your answer so I can delete the question I am going to break it into new separate ones

Comment: No, free to do it, i can not find where to delete here on mobile, will do later today